# Enable multi file upload in nextjs with upload.io

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, file-upload, upload

I'm on this next's app where I use upload.io for uploads and replicate.com for an ai model, I can upload 1 picture but I can't upload multiple. Anyone see the problem here?

```
import { AnimatePresence, motion } from "framer-motion";
import { NextPage } from "next";
import Head from "next/head";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { UploadDropzone } from "react-uploader";
import { Uploader } from "uploader";
import { CompareSlider } from "../components/CompareSlider";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import LoadingDots from "../components/LoadingDots";
import ResizablePanel from "../components/ResizablePanel";
import Toggle from "../components/Toggle";
import appendNewToName from "../utils/appendNewToName";
import downloadPhoto from "../utils/downloadPhoto";
import DropDown from "../components/DropDown";
import { roomType, rooms, themeType, themes } from "../utils/dropdownTypes";
import { GenerateResponseData } from "./api/generate";
import { useSession, signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import useSWR from "swr";
import { Rings } from "react-loader-spinner";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { Toaster, toast } from "react-hot-toast";

// Configuration for the uploader
const uploader = Uploader({
  apiKey: !!process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_UPLOAD_API_KEY
    ? process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_UPLOAD_API_KEY
    : "free",
});

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [originalPhoto, setOriginalPhoto] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [restoredImage, setRestoredImage] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [restoredLoaded, setRestoredLoaded] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [sideBySide, setSideBySide] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [photoName, setPhotoName] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<themeType>("Modern");
  const [room, setRoom] = useState<roomType>("Living Room");

  const fetcher = (url: string) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());
  const { data, mutate } = useSWR("/api/remaining", fetcher);
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();

  const options = {
    multi: true,

    maxFileCount: 1,
    mimeTypes: ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpg"],
    editor: { images: { crop: false } },
    // tags: [data?.remainingGenerations > 3 ? "paid" : "free"],
    styles: {
      colors: {
        primary: "#2563EB", // Primary buttons & links
        error: "#d23f4d", // Error messages
        shade100: "#5A5A5A", // Standard text
        shade200: "#fffe", // Secondary button text
        shade300: "#fffd", // Secondary button text (hover)
        shade400: "#5A5A5A", // Welcome text
        shade500: "#fff9", // Modal close button
        shade600: "#5A5A5A", // Border
        shade700: "#fff2", // Progress indicator background
        shade800: "#fff1", // File item background
        shade900: "#ffff", // Various (draggable crop buttons, etc.)
      },
    },
    onValidate: async (file: File): Promise<undefined | string> => {
      return data.remainingGenerations === 0
        ? `No more credits left. Buy more above.`
        : undefined;
    },
  };

  const UploadDropZone = () => (
    <UploadDropzone
      uploader={uploader}
      options={options}


      onUpdate={(file) => {
        if (file.length !== 0) {
          setPhotoName(file[0].originalFile.originalFileName);
          setOriginalPhoto(file[0].fileUrl.replace("raw", "thumbnail"));
          generatePhoto(file[0].fileUrl.replace("raw", "thumbnail"));
        }
      }}
      width="670px"
      height="250px"

    />
  );

  async function generatePhoto(fileUrl: string) {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 200));
    setLoading(true);
    const res = await fetch("/api/generate", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ imageUrl: fileUrl, theme, room }),
    });

    let response = (await res.json()) as GenerateResponseData;
    if (res.status !== 200) {
      setError(response as any);
    } else {
      mutate();
      const rooms =
        (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("rooms") || "[]") as string[]) || [];
      rooms.push(response.id);
      localStorage.setItem("rooms", JSON.stringify(rooms));
      setRestoredImage(response.generated);
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false);
    }, 1300);
  }

  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (router.query.success === "true") {
      toast.success("Payment successful!");
    }
  }, [router.query.success]);

  return (<div className="bg-white">
    <div className="flex max-w-6xl mx-auto flex-col items-center justify-center py-2 min-h-screen">
      <Head>
        <title>ProPhotoshoot.io</title>
      </Head>
      <Header
        photo={session?.user?.image || undefined}
        email={session?.user?.email || undefined}
      />
      <main className="flex flex-1 w-full flex-col items-center justify-center text-center px-4 mt-4 sm:mb-0 mb-8">
        {status === "authenticated" ? (
          <Link
            href="/buy-credits"
            className="border border-black rounded-2xl py-2 px-4 text-black text-sm my-6 duration-300 ease-in-out hover:text-black hover:scale-105 transition"
          >
            Pricing is now available.{" "}
            <span className="font-semibold text-blue-600 ">Click here</span> to
            buy credits!
          </Link>
        ) : (
          <a
            href="https://twitter.com/nutlope/status/1635674124738523139?cxt=HHwWhsCz1ei8irMtAAAA"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
            className="border border-black rounded-2xl py-2 px-4 text-black text-sm my-6 duration-300 ease-in-out hover:text-gray-300 transition"
          >
            Over{" "}
            <span className="font-semibold text-blue-600">1 million users</span>{" "}
            have used ProPhotoshoot.io so far
          </a>
        )}
        <h1 className="mx-auto max-w-4xl font-display text-4xl font-bold tracking-normal  text-black sm:text-6xl mb-5">
          Generate your <span className="text-blue-600">A.I</span> photoshoot
        </h1>
        {status === "authenticated" && data && !restoredImage && (
          <p className="text-black">
            You have{" "}
            <span className="font-semibold text-blue-600">
              {data.remainingGenerations}{" "}
              {data?.remainingGenerations > 1 ? "credits" : "credit"}
            </span>{" "}
            left.{" "}
            {data.remainingGenerations < 2 && (
              <span>
                Buy more credits{" "}
                <Link
                  href="/buy-credits"
                  className="font-semibold text-gray-300 underline underline-offset-2 hover:text-gray-200 transition"
                >
                  here
                </Link>
                .
              </span>
            )}
          </p>
        )}
        <ResizablePanel>
          <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
            <motion.div className="flex justify-between items-center w-full flex-col mt-4">
              {restoredImage && (
                <div>
                  Here's your remodeled <b>{room.toLowerCase()}</b> in the{" "}
                  <b>{theme.toLowerCase()}</b> theme!{" "}
                </div>
              )}
              <div
                className={`${restoredLoaded ? "visible mt-6 -ml-8" : "invisible"
                  }`}
              >
                <Toggle
                  className={`${restoredLoaded ? "visible mb-6" : "invisible"}`}
                  sideBySide={sideBySide}
                  setSideBySide={(newVal) => setSideBySide(newVal)}
                />
              </div>
              {restoredLoaded && sideBySide && (
                <CompareSlider
                  original={originalPhoto!}
                  restored={restoredImage!}
                />
              )}
              {status === "loading" ? (
                <div className="max-w-[670px] h-[250px] flex justify-center items-center">
                  <Rings
                    height="100"
                    width="100"
                    color="white"
                    radius="6"
                    wrapperStyle={{}}
                    wrapperClass=""
                    visible={true}
                    ariaLabel="rings-loading"
                  />
                </div>
              ) : status === "authenticated" && !originalPhoto ? (
                <>
                  <div className="space-y-4 w-full max-w-sm">
                    <div className="flex mt-3 items-center space-x-3">
                      <Image
                        src="/number-1-white.svg"
                        width={30}
                        height={30}
                        alt="1 icon"
                      />
                      <p className="text-left font-medium text-black">
                        Choose your outfit.
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <DropDown
                      theme={theme}
                      // @ts-ignore
                      setTheme={(newTheme) => setTheme(newTheme)}
                      themes={themes}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="space-y-4 w-full max-w-sm">
                    <div className="flex mt-10 items-center space-x-3">
                      <Image
                        src="/number-2-white.svg"
                        width={30}
                        height={30}
                        alt="1 icon"
                      />
                      <p className="text-left font-medium text-black">
                        Choose your background.
                      </p>
                    </div>
                    <DropDown
                      theme={room}
                      // @ts-ignore
                      setTheme={(newRoom) => setRoom(newRoom)}
                      themes={rooms}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="mt-4 w-full max-w-sm">
                    <div className="flex mt-6 w-96 items-center space-x-3">
                      <Image
                        src="/number-3-white.svg"
                        width={30}
                        height={30}
                        alt="1 icon"
                      />
                      <p className="text-left font-medium">
                        Upload a picture of yourself.
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <UploadDropZone />
                </>
              ) : (
                !originalPhoto && (
                  <div className="h-[250px] flex flex-col items-center space-y-6 max-w-[670px] -mt-8">
                    <div className="max-w-xl text-black">
                      Sign in below with Google to create a free account and
                      redesign your room today. You will get 3 generations for
                      free.
                    </div>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => signIn("google")}
                      className="bg-gray-200 text-black font-semibold py-3 px-6 rounded-2xl flex items-center space-x-2"
                    >
                      <Image
                        src="/google.png"
                        width={20}
                        height={20}
                        alt="google's logo"
                      />
                      <span>Sign in with Google</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                )
              )}
              {originalPhoto && !restoredImage && (
                <Image
                  alt="original photo"
                  src={originalPhoto}
                  className="rounded-2xl h-96"
                  width={475}
                  height={475}
                />
              )}
              {restoredImage && originalPhoto && !sideBySide && (
                <div className="flex sm:space-x-4 sm:flex-row flex-col">
                  <div>
                    <h2 className="mb-1 font-medium text-lg">Original Room</h2>
                    <Image
                      alt="original photo"
                      src={originalPhoto}
                      className="rounded-2xl relative w-full h-96"
                      width={475}
                      height={475}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="sm:mt-0 mt-8">
                    <h2 className="mb-1 font-medium text-lg">Generated Room</h2>
                    <a href={restoredImage} target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
                      <Image
                        alt="restored photo"
                        src={restoredImage}
                        className="rounded-2xl relative sm:mt-0 mt-2 cursor-zoom-in w-full h-96"
                        width={475}
                        height={475}
                        onLoadingComplete={() => setRestoredLoaded(true)}
                      />
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
              {loading && (
                <button
                  disabled
                  className="bg-blue-500 rounded-full text-white font-medium px-4 pt-2 pb-3 mt-8 w-40"
                >
                  <span className="pt-4">
                    <LoadingDots color="white" style="large" />
                  </span>
                </button>
              )}
              {error && (
                <div
                  className="bg-red-100 border border-red-400 text-red-700 px-4 py-3 rounded-xl mt-8 max-w-[575px]"
                  role="alert"
                >
                  <div className="bg-red-500 text-white font-bold rounded-t px-4 py-2">
                    Please try again later.
                  </div>
                  <div className="border border-t-0 border-red-400 rounded-b bg-red-100 px-4 py-3 text-red-700">
                    {error}
                  </div>
                </div>
              )}
              <div className="flex space-x-2 justify-center">
                {originalPhoto && !loading && !error && (
                  <button
                    onClick={() => {
                      setOriginalPhoto(null);
                      setRestoredImage(null);
                      setRestoredLoaded(false);
                      setError(null);
                    }}
                    className="bg-blue-500 rounded-full text-white font-medium px-4 py-2 mt-8 hover:bg-blue-500/80 transition"
                  >
                    Generate New Room
                  </button>
                )}
                {restoredLoaded && (
                  <button
                    onClick={() => {
                      downloadPhoto(
                        restoredImage!,
                        appendNewToName(photoName!)
                      );
                    }}
                    className="bg-white rounded-full text-black border font-medium px-4 py-2 mt-8 hover:bg-gray-100 transition"
                  >
                    Download Generated Room
                  </button>
                )}
              </div>
            </motion.div>
          </AnimatePresence>
        </ResizablePanel>
        <Toaster position="top-center" reverseOrder={false} />
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </div></div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

I specified in the 'const options' multi: true, which should make it work but it doesn't, here is the code.
As well I changed the   maxFileCount but that didn't work neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example has `maxFileCount: 1` -- you mentioned you've changed this, but just highlighting it nonetheless, as this will prevent multiple files.

Furthermore, if you're updating the `options` object *after* the `UploadDropzone` component is rendered, you will need to force a re-render by adding `<UploadDropzone key={someNewValue}` (this is due to a limitation in `react-uploader` whereby it currently doesn't update based on prop changes).

Comment: Thanks for your reply as a beginner I only know about keys as I map true an array. Do you mean something like this.?  const UploadDropZone = () => (
    <UploadDropzone
      uploader={uploader}
      options={options}
      key={12345}

Comment: That's right: the 'key' prop simply destroys/recreates the component each time the value changes, so you can set it to something random each time you change the uploader options.

Comment: I found the solution I changed the on update prop for the onComplete, this allows me to do multiple updates.